# UDK: Toggle Material on Brushes?

Tags: udk

I'm attempting to change / toggle the material that's applied to a BSP brush. I've seen where it's possible on static meshes, but I can't seem to get it to work on brushes. Below is an example scenario.

1. The ground (BSP Brush) is covered in a stone material
2. The player hits a trigger.
3. A new "moss" material is applied to the brush, removing the old stone material.

Any assistance you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did quite a bit of research and it looks like this isn't possible in UDK. A material applied to a BSP is static and cannot be changed dynamically in game.